# Is there a review queue on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, meta

I have suggested some edits to be reviewed, but I noticed that there is no review button at the topbar. So how does the peer-editing process work *on this site*?

Comment: The review link only appears if you have enough reputation to see it. **I** see it just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters on MSO? I'm pretty sure I have enough rep to see it..

Comment: 266 is not enough.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit <-- you need 2k

Comment: So I'm guessing there's no First Posts and Lte Answers here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works just the same as on any other Stack Exchange website; there is a suggested edit review queue (to which you would not have access yet).

The review link is only shown if you have enough reputation to review *anything*. For Meta, that is [2000 points, the ability to edit by yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). There are no Late Answer and First Post queues here, so there are no queues that would be visible at a lower reputation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the suggested edit given by you can not be reviewed by you.

Second there is no [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) or [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) review queue on Meta. So to see review link at the topbar you need at least [2000 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) on Meta for Suggested Edits and Low Quality Posts.

Comment: This is correct: I cannot review a suggested edit I submitted, as I surely think the edit is helpful.